# Getting the angle from 3 vectors, without excluding non-reflex of obtuse angles

Tags: javascript, math, vector, angle

So I struggled last two days and found many answers but I have modified one

```
findAngle(c, b, a) {

    const ab = {x: b.x - a.x, y: b.y - a.y};
    const cb = {x: b.x - c.x, y: b.y - c.y};

    const dot = (ab.x * cb.x + ab.y * cb.y); // dot product
    const cross = (ab.x * cb.y - ab.y * cb.x); // cross product

    let alpha = Math.atan2(cross, dot);
    if (alpha < 0) {
      alpha = (Math.PI * 2 + alpha);
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

im not sure its right, I don't like the alpha < 0 portion can anyone suggest a better opinion

Comment: What do you mean by "the angle from 3 vectors"? Which angle exactly? Don't you only need 2 vectors to make an angle? Please provide an illustration or other means to clarify.

Comment: Currently your question is quite unclear. Please specify in clear what it is you are trying to achieve and how your current code fails by comparison with the desired result.

Comment: it seems to be right http://davdata.nl/math/vectdirection.html

Comment: Whenever you have two intersecting vectors, you always end up with two angles (one bigger than 180deg and one smaller), except when they're equal, in which case your two vectors are only one. How exactly are you supposed to know which is the correct angle? The only solution is to a-priory decide you'll always get the clockwise angle or the counter-clockwise one. Anyways, here's a [tiny toy](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/tph36qc1/) I made while trying to understand your problem. You might find it useful, even though it's always returning the smaller angle.

Comment: This code calculates angle needed to rotate vector `cb` to make it collinear with vector `ab`. `a,b,c` are points here. Now it's time to know - what do you really need ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// assuming that b is the point at which you want to find the angle (formed by vectors bc and ba) 
const angle = (c, b, a) => {
  const bc = {x: c.x - b.x, y: c.y - b.y};
  const ba = {x: a.x - b.x, y: a.y - b.y};
  // the cosine of the angle between the two vectors is their dot product divided by the product of their magnitudes
  const cos = (bc.x * ba.x + bc.y * ba.y) / (Math.hypot(bc.x, bc.y) * Math.hypot(ba.x, ba.y));
  // return the angle in degrees
  return 180 * Math.acos(cos) / Math.PI;
}
console.log(angle({x: 3, y: 4}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: -3, y: -4})); // the angle between two opposite vectors
console.log(angle({x: 0, y: 4}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 4, y: 0})); // the angle between two perpendicular vectors
console.log(angle({x: 3, y: 4}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 4, y: 3}));
```